# $\iint_A F\cdot n\, dS$ region bounded by $x^2+y^2=1$ and $-1\le z\le 2$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, divergence-operator

> This is the question: we need to find the outward flux and verify it using divergence theorem 
>   [image]

The main query is that i solved it normally first using $\iint F\cdot n\,dS$ and i got incorrect answer as $3\pi$
 and when i solve it using divergence theorem i got the correct answer as $6\pi$.

**Can yu please find my mistake?**

Here is my solution:

Now one more thing : **what is the condition to use green's theorem and stoke's theorem why are they not valid here as i am getting curl 0 so answer will be 0 according to stoke's theorem. The question is how to know when do we use stoke's green's or divergence theorem ?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divergence theorem deals with a 3d body $B$, its boundary surface $\partial B$, and a vector field $F$ defined in a neighborhood of $B$. It says that
$$\int_{\partial B} F\cdot n\>{\rm d}\omega=\int_B{\rm div}(F)\>{\rm d}V\ ,$$
where ${\rm d}\omega$ denotes the scalar surface element on $\partial B$.

In your case $B$ is the upright finite cylinder, bounded by $\partial B=C+D_{-1}+D_2$ with $\>C:=\{x^2+y^2=1, \> -1\leq z\leq2\}$ and  two discs at levels $z=-1$ and $z=2$. In your calculation you have just computed the flux $\int_C F\cdot n\>{\rm d}\omega$ through the side wall $C$ of the cylinder. It remains to compute the flux through the bottom disc $D_{-1}$ (where $n=(0,0,-1)$) and the top disc $D_2$ (where $n=(0,0,1)$).

Comment: flux of F means? i have calculated over the side surface only... kinda agree with it but needs to visualise it. But thanks I understand my mistake .. outward flux they mean array of arrows pointing outward from the object from everywhre am i right ?

Comment: I tried finding the flux over top and bottom and I feel they get cancelled out so the answer remains same.. please tell how to obtain them correctly.

Comment: @learningstudent: They definitely do not cancel. Notice that $z^2=4$ on the top and $z^2=1$ on the bottom.

Comment: Ohhhh yeah... I got it... Hahaha thanks.. that's a careless mistake I did... I took it as 4 for both case.. thanks ! Got it